# Parse and iOS register details

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am new to parse and developing. I created an app in swift and I am trying to transfer various fields from my register screen to Parse.com. I do not know how to actually accomplish the specifics in my application.

I pieced my code from various videos on youtube.But I get errors with most of the "newUser.* = *" part of the code. the only ones that do not error out are the items that already exist in the user class. I added columns but still no go.

```
@IBAction func registerTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var firstname = self.firstNameField.text
    var lastname = self.lastNameField.text
    var email = self.emailAdressField.text
    var businessname = self.businessNameField.text
    var foodconcept = self.foodConceptField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text
    var businessphonenumber = self.businessPhoneNumberField.text


    if (passwordField != confirmPasswordField){

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Passwords do not match", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")

    } else {

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.firstname = firstname
        newUser.lastname = lastname
        newUser.email = email
        newuser.businessname = businessname
        newUser.foodconcept = foodconcept
        newUser.password = password
        newUser.businessphonenumber = businessphonenumber


        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((error) != nil) {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alert.show()



            } else {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Registered", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alert.show()

            }

        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter details for custom columns like this.
For for information you should check the [Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide)

As of now, you can solve this by changing the lines :

```
newuser["your_custom_column_name"] = value;
```

Parse class is a predefined class and it does not have any methods to include all the custom columns which you make so they have used the above method to do so.

Hope this helps :)